# Chrome fails to download response body if HTTP status is an error code

Tags: http, express, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Node.js Express web server that returns an HTTP response JSON payload along with an error status (4xx or 5xx) when something goes wrong.

```
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' });
```

From the Chrome browser developer console's Timing section, I can see a lot of time (up to 5 minutes) spent in the "Content Download" segment and ultimately I am getting "Failed to load response data" in the Response section after download fails.

[Chrome developer console timing output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQaxT.png)

Other browsers like Firefox and Opera are able to successfully download the JSON payload successfully and display them in their respective developer consoles.

If I send back the HTTP status as 200, Chrome has no trouble downloading the payload.

Also, if I do not set the Cache-Control HTTP headers to "no-store, no cache...", Chrome is able to successfully download the payload with 4xx/5xx status. However, I would like to set this header as a good practice against cache misuse.

[HTTP Response Headers in the success and failure case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAqcH.png)

Is there something specific I need to do for Chrome?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Same problem here, trying to return JSON details with the 500 and content-type is correct, but not getting anywhere with Chrome showing that to me even though from curl for instance I can see the JSON body just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar problem. For the request I used the `fetch` API and in case of an error I did not read the stream of the response body.

Neither the content of the response body was displayed in the devtools nor was the request included in the `HAR` export.

After debugging this in the console I noticed that the content is displayed in the response or preview tab as soon as I was reading the stream. (e.g.: `await response.text()`)

Strangely enough the behavior changes as you described when the corresponding cache headers are not set.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened when nothing was awaiting the response body.

Before (no body is rendered in the preview tab):

```js
async request(context: RequestOpts): Promise<Response> {
    // ...
    const response = await this.fetchApi(url, init);
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response;
    }
    throw new Error();
}
```

After:

```js
async request(context: RequestOpts): Promise<Response> {
    // ...
    const response = await this.fetchApi(url, init);
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response;
    }
    throw await response.json();
}
```